# Open Graph Beta: define action, object, and publishing

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to learn and test out the new open graph beta that allows you to define actions, objects, and publish them.  I believe I'm following the tutorial and doing exactly what it says, but the defined actions are not publishing.  I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me discover what I'm doing wrong.  Here's the details:

For the object, here's what I get when I click get code: (I'm changing header links since I can't post more than 2 links on my account)
     `<head prefix="og: htp://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# bible_app: 
      http://ogp.me/ns/fb/bible_app#">
     <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="223527597700292"> 
     <meta property="og:type"        content="bible_app:verse"> 
     <meta property="og:url"         content="Put Your Own URL Here"> 
     <meta property="og:title"       content="Sample Verse"> 
     <meta property="og:description" content="Some Arbitrary String"> 
     <meta property="og:image"       content="https://s-
      static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png">`

For og:url, I have tried the actual page where I have the object: bibleverses4.me/app/learn.html  and  I've also tried the sample url samples.ogp.me/225426837510368.

For the action, I just modified the tutorial:

```
    `FB.api('/me/bible_app:learn' + 
                '?learn=http://bibleverse4.me/app/learn.html','post',
                function(response)`
```

For the url in the action, I have tried both the above url and the sample FB gives.

The end result and problem: everything shows up, but when I click the "Learn" button, it says

> The page at Bibleverses4.me says: 
>   Error occured

So, I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong here, but I'm trying to learn and would greatly appreciate any help that could be offered.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it should be:

```
FB.api('/me/bible_app:learn' + 
                '?verse=http://bibleverse4.me/app/learn.html','post',
                function(response)
```

Where the /me/bible_app:learn is your action and verse is your object...

Comment: I tried to make *verse* bold in the sample but it didn't quite work... the change is from ?learn to ?verse.

Comment: Thanks so much Carl! :)  You were absolutely right!  I just tried it, and it worked great.  I see how I was messing up now, and your help has been greatly appreciated. Thanks again.